# Best approach to display dynamic fields as per the condition in angular

Tags: angular

I would like to display fields based on certain conditions,My form has some 80 fields and Do I need to give 80 conditions Or is there a better approach to it like store in json data and display as per the json data,Please recommend me the best approach in angular.

Comment: Too general question. Give examples of existing code with fields and conditions (at least 2) and define “better” e.g. what are you trying to optimize (performance/readability/supportability/other).

Comment: I am trying to optimize readability of code as maintaining 80 fields would be hassle in the long run of the application

Comment: And also some are hidden,some are disabled and some are dependent on other fields.

Comment: Too general question. Try to encapsulate fields and reuse them. Maybe ng-content can help u